# Unable to get background image to display full screen on webpage after using a script

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am writing a landing page using bootstrap 4 and am trying to have a background that changes every few seconds and is mobile friendly. I figured out the code to get the images to change but now I can't figure out how to incorporate the img-responsive class.

```
<section id="fh5co-home" data-section="home" style="background-image: url(images/pretty-bastard-client-lounge.jpg);" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <script>
  var images = [
        "images/pretty-bastard-dallas-print-studio.jpg",
        "images/pretty-bastard-lobby.jpg",
        "images/pretty-bastard-sound-stage.jpg",
        "images/pretty-bastard-studio-walls.jpg",
  ]
  var imageHead = document.getElementById("fh5co-home");
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
      imageHead.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
      i = i + 1;
      if (i == images.length) {
        i =  0;
      }
  }, 7000);
  </script>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#fh5co-home {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #fh5co-home {
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: initial;
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `min-height:100vh`?

Comment: Additionally, you may consider modifying a "carousel" component. I believe bootstrap has one.

Comment: example: https://jsfiddle.net/jdell64/nfyj5gb9/3/  you'd still have to make the bg size to the page, but that is a problem that has been answered a few times on this site.

Comment: min-height:100vh fixed the issue! thank you @ShubhamVerma

Answer (score 0):

There is no height and you are probably not waiting for 7 seconds. You don't even have a closing section tag

```
<section id="fh5co-home" data-section="home" style="background-image: url(images/pretty-bastard-client-lounge.jpg);"
    data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"> </section>
<script>
    var images = [
        "images/pretty-bastard-dallas-print-studio.jpg",
        "images/pretty-bastard-lobby.jpg",
        "images/pretty-bastard-sound-stage.jpg",
        "images/pretty-bastard-studio-walls.jpg",
    ]
    var imageHead = document.getElementById("fh5co-home");
    imageHead.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/pretty-bastard-dallas-print-studio.jpg";
    var i = 1;
    setInterval(function () {
        imageHead.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
        i = i + 1;
        if (i == images.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }, 7000);


</script>
```

CSS:

```
#fh5co-home {
  /* background-color: transparent; */
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  height:1000px;
  background-image: url("images/pretty-bastard-dallas-print-studio.jpg");
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #fh5co-home {
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: initial;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. it was definitely the height property. I have a closing section tag but it is further below in my code